# Folder Name Convention Java

Tags: convention

What do you call a folder where you save information (Games saves, highscores, etc). Its just a naming conventioon question. By default you have src and for resources you can make a fodler called res and add it to the build path. I just want to ask out of curiosity what one would call a folder where you write information. I was thinking either sav (for save) or writ (for write). I'm using eclipse so i know how to add the folders to the buildpath.

Comment: I've seen `sav` before.  Regardless, I'm not sure this question is Java specific. (It has the java tag currently.)

Comment: definitely has nothing to do with eclipse.  Java, maybe, I know technologies like Maven enjoy imposing a rigid, fixed structure.

Comment: This folder really shouldn't be part of your project. Also, name it `Saved Games`. (Or just dump all your files under a folder with your app's name in the appropriate user data directory for a given OS. `C:\Users\John\Documents\AppName`, `~/Library/Application Support/AppName`, whateverthehell on Linux.)

Comment: *Never* put spaces in the filenames, it makes life complex for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not under `src`, since it's output, not...  source.
2. Highly application specific and depends on requirements you haven't spelled out.  Does this need to be accessible to all users?  Just one?  From remote processes?  Persistent between runs of the application?  Automatically backed up / persisted?  In a Dropbox?  Loaded into MySQL?  etc.  Obviously the answers to this will vary between applications, and so will where the output should be.

Comment: I never said under src? Im just asking for what one would name the folder out of curiosity. Just instead of saving a game highscore/stats to a text file where people can edit it, it would just update the actual game file, which has a folder contains the text file. Well thats an example but really all im looking for is how people usually name their folders

Comment: @Exikle That makes your question a poll, and thus not appropriate for SO. Naming is arbitrary, pick whatever and stick to it if the name is all you're looking for.

Comment: @Exikle - more precisely - often there are conventions that everyone follows (e.g. `src/main/resources` is where classpath resources appear in everyone Maven project), and the correct answer to this question is "it depends / there isn't one."  But asking what people do in lack of convention is a poll, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this dynamic data created by the program?  If so why would you have these files in your build?

For dynamic data the java.util.prefs package provides a potential cross platform solution, e.g. registry for windows and ~/.directories on linux.

Comment: To be fair, the registry is a terrible location for data as complex as saved game state.

Comment: @millimoose  You are probably right if we are talking loads of binary data.  Highscores would be good candidate though.  Thought I'd mention it as a something to consider, on reflection a comment would probably have been a better outlet for my words.